# How to configure systemd to start and monitor a service in RHEL 7

Tags: centos, rhel, systemd, watchdog, rhel7

We are upgrading to RHEL 7. We have our own platform watchdog but now we want to use watchdog provided by RHEL 7. I need to know how can I configure RHEL 7 watchdog to start and monitor a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you will need is [here](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/watchdog.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add new service into /etc/systemd/system/
For example: my.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Our service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vde_switch --tap tap0 --mode 0660 \
 --dirmode 0750 --group qemu

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Next

```
systemctl start my.service
```